# Group by formula field in report

Tags: crystal-reports

To start from the beginning I had a long memo line that I needed to strip down to only show me a specific name in the string.  Here is an example of the original memo line my report was giving me:

*Ex. PLUMBERS-ACH distribution from share suffix 9 [2] 19.00 01DEC2017*

I created three different formulas to strip down the memo line to only show me text before the "-".  Here are those formulas:

**Formula 1:**

```
Left({SH_HIST.trn_memo}, instr(1,{SH_HIST.trn_memo},"-")-1)
```

**Formula 2:**

```
replace({Formula 1}, "-", " ")
```

**Formula 3:**

```
If instr({SH_HIST.trn_memo}, "-")>0 then {@Formula 2} else {SH_HIST.trn_memo}
```

I then placed Formula 3 into the report to give me the desired output from the memo line (this returns output successfully).  Now I need to sort by that field because I need to be able to group all like items and sum them.  When I click on "Insert Group" and select Formula 3 then try to preview the report I get the following message:

> string length is less than 0 or not an integer

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to fix this, please?  I've googled my heart out.

Comment: Why don't you make 1 more field in your table and calculate all those 3 formulas before you call crystal report? It's easier to then group by that field and it's value that way.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 3 formulas why don't you try this:

```
Split(Column,"-")[1] //Provided the format you gave applies for all records
```

Now group by this formula

Comment: Can you accept it as answered and close thr thread so that others can use